# Prove nonexistence of a countable basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Let us consider space $R = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of infinite sequences of real numbers. I have to prove two claims:

1. Let $a_i=(0,0,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$; $1$ at i-th place. Then $B=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ is not a basis of $R$.
2. It can proved with the Zorn lemma that there *is* basis in $R$. Prove that there is no *countable* basis in $R$.

My attempt:

1. Let us consider sequence $A=(1, 1, \ldots)$ (all $1$). Since linear combination is by definition *finite* then it is clear that we can not express $A$ as finite linear combination of sequences from $B$, because any linear combination of sequences from $B$ would have only finite number of nonzero elements.
2. Well, honestly I do not know to solve this. I think we should do something like this - assume that there is countable basis $B'$. Then we should construct a sequence that does not belong to $\operatorname{span}(B')$ explicitly or use some set-theoretic theorems about cardinalities that $\operatorname{span}(B')$ has smaller size compared to $R$. However while I am pretty sure about the approach we should take, I do not see how to execute it.

So my questions are:

1. Is $1$ is correct/make sense?
2. How to approach $2$?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Spanning seems the more obvious counter example. Take a look at the proof that the reals are uncountable. I believe the trick you need is in there.

Comment: For number 2, do you know the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @Mark I will learn it now and see what I can do.

Comment: By basis, do you mean a vector space basis or a topological basis?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Vector space basis.

Comment: I don't know what $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ means, seeing as the $a_i$ are not sets, they are sequences.

Comment: For number 2) I think you could argue as follows: if there were a countable basis, then there would also be a countable dense set, so it suffices to show that there can't be one. To show that there can't be a countable dense set, given the particular nature of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, you can use a diagonal Cantor-style argument. (I'm not sure about this, I didn't check the details. But if you don't want to use Baire's theorem could be an alternative approach)